# Am I looking at the right place for EBITDA for Detour Gold?

Tags: stocks

I heard my friend say that the EV/EBITDA multiple for Detour Gold is about 7 or 8.  And he wrote this:

> $22.21 per share in CAD
>
> 177 outstanding shares
>
> Equals $4 billion market cap
>
> Minus $191 million in cash
>
> Plus $148 million in debt
>
> Equals $4 billion enterprise value
>
> *$514 million estimate for 2020 EBITDA*
>
> **Equals 7.6 EV/EBITDA multiple**

I was able to follow along until the $514 million estimate for 2020 EBITDA.  I looked at their [2019Q3 report](https://s22.q4cdn.com/327131108/files/doc_financials/2019/q3/DGC_Financials-Q3-2019.pdf) and I see this on page 3:

[image]

Doesn't that mean they are probably only going to have an EBITDA of about $100M to $150M for end of 2019?  And when I look on a [webpage like this](https://www.marketscreener.com/DETOUR-GOLD-CORPORATION-1409731/financials/), I see mentions of EBITDA $275M for 2018, $338 for 2019 and $387M for 2020.

Also, on page 7 of [the Detour Gold 2018Q4 Report](https://s22.q4cdn.com/327131108/files/doc_financials/2018/Q4/DGC-Q4-18-FS.PDF), I see a 2018 year end EBITDA of $102.6M.  Which is completely off  from the $275M mentioned above

So basically, I'm not sure where to actually read the EBITDA values?